# Show blue dot in chrome tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications

I'd like to know how to show the blue "notification" dot on a tab. Something like this

[image: Reddit notification dot]

But every page I search, says something about pinning, and chrome deleted this function. Well, how is Reddit doing it then (while it's not being pinned as well)? **Does someone know?** It will obviously have to be JavaScript. I basically only use Chrome, so another question would be, **do other browsers also have such functionality?**

Comment: Really? It's just a different favicon? I'll look at it again once it pops up again.

Comment: @Burnee Alright, it actually is, here is the link for it https://www.redditstatic.com/desktop2x/img/favicon/badged-favicon-16x16.png